# Excel VBA Search Outlook GAL Using ExchangeUser Alias Property

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am trying to search trough a 200,000 plus Outlook GAL using Excel VBA and the only thing I have as a search parameter is the alias property.

This can be done from the Outlook >> Address Book >> Advanced Find dialog and it returns a result quite fast.

I tried something like going trough each item, calling the ExchangeUser object and compare the Alias property against my search but it takes way to long.

The source is a monthly report that contains and ever changing Excel list of about 100 Aliases and each must be searched in an Outlook GAL with over 200,000 entries.

Is there a way to do it pragmatically from Excel that responds as fast as the outlook dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

1. Use `Application.Session.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve` and hope the alias resolves and there are no ambiguous entries. the search will be performed in all address book containers on the search path.
2. Use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) to have a restriction to be applied to GAL. Note that only very particular restriction can be applied - you would need to open the `PR_SEARCH` property as `IMAPIContainer`, set `PR_ALIAS` property, call `IMAPIContainer::GetSearchCriteria`, then apply that criteria to the GAL contents table.
3. Use Redemption (any language, I am its author) - it exposes the [RDOAddressListSearch](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressListSearch.htm) object